# How can I do the basic authentication with database,Spring boot and Restful webservices?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication, restful-authentication

I have done the server-side application with **Spring-boot, Spring Data JPA, Basic authentication and RESTFul webservices**

It is working as expected when I do authentication **(login - `http://localhost:8080/server-side/login` or logout - `http://localhost:8080/server-side/logout`)**  from my client application(AngularJS) .

But If I give wrong credentials for login http://localhost:8080/server-side/login my **browser asks to enter credentials to login**.

But I want it has to be handled by my application not by my browser.

I followed the tutorial http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-basic-authentication/

Comment: Fixed my issue by adding the following code in my BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint.java Since currently i'm login from a "form".

response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "FormBased");  But I want the solution if i'm not login from a "form"